# Set and get owner of azure container registry image

Tags: azure, docker, containers, azure-container-registry

Context: We are managing a central azure container registry which is holding around 350 repository. Each repositories are having good amount of image. Now because of Log4J issue, we are trying to inform all image owner to take care of their repositories. Because there is no owner name associated with images/repo, we are not able to find who they are and not able to communication.

I am trying to find a way how we can set owner name to image in azure container registry so that i can extract and send communication to them.

Comment: Hello @Den Wahlin, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I tested in my environment where multiple images have built by many user in a ACR.

But it doesn’t record who created the images in ACR.

For Workaround There is two way you can track who has created an image in ACR

1. you can look at the activity log to see who the last user is who pushed the image to a particular repository. Please keep in mind that the activity logs are kept for 90 days by default.
2. Another way you can do is introduce a process in your team to create the images with a tag on theirs name or specific ID if any.

For information you can refer this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-container-registry-preview-of-diagnostics-and-audit-logs/